# Reactjs => axios post method ERROR not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I wanted to console log the statement but the axios post method seems not to be working
it shows no error tho

It logs the user value but doesn't show the  "User added"

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
    }

    console.log(user);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add',user)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
      username: ""
    })
```

user.js

```
router.route("/add").post((req,res)=>{
  const username = req.body.username;
  const newUser = new User({username});
  newUser.save()
    .then(()=> res.json("User added!"))
    .catch(err=> res.status(400).json("Error "+err))
});
```

but its not logging "User added"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that i have to run both the backend and frontend server simultaneously which in my case is `react and nodejs` now its working just fine!

Comment: If you feel that your own answer has answered your question, then you can 'accept' it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Give Username directly instead of passing it as obj may be it work

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
      username: this.state.username,
    

    console.log(user);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add',username)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
      username: ""
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

.save() method doesn't returning anything here, you can return a promise
Also change the way of sending json response.

```
 router.route("/add").post((req,res)=>{
      const username = req.body.username;
      const newUser = new User({username});
       return newUser.save()
        .then(()=> res.json({success: true, message: "User added!"}))
        .catch(err=> res.status(400).json({message:"Error "+err}))
    });
```